# How to create a jar file on Apache NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar

I'm using Apache NetBeans 12.4 and still I can not figure it out to make a Jar file using this newer version. Can I have help?

Comment: Looks like you are using Maven. Show us the (a) the contents of your `pom.xml` and (b) the output from your "Clean and Build" (Shift+F11). The output should include a line telling you about the JAR: `Building jar: ...`.

Comment: Another way to check: In the left hand project navigator, change from the "Projects" tab to the "Files" tab, navigate to your project and look in the "target" folder. You should see the jar file there (if it exists).

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. The ja was there.

Comment: How can I make a stand alone jar which can be run in the command line using 
>>> java -jar mavenproject2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?

Comment: That is a completely different question from the one you asked in your question. It has actually been asked several times before on this site. Have you done any research? I am sure there are several excellent answers already.